# React Hooks - useEffect still being called even when object is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a question on React Hooks.  This is a sample of my code :-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Card from "./Card";

const CardsBoard = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    doRatingClickProcessing()
  }, [ratingObj])

  const doRatingClickProcessing = () => {
    const { player, title, rating } = ratingObj
  }

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid justify-content-center">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <Card
              cardInfo={player1Card}
              player={1}
              showCard={visiblePl1}
              clickableRatings = {clickableRatings}
              onClick={ratingObj => setRatingObj(ratingObj)}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <Card
              cardInfo={player2Card}
              player={2}
              showCard={visiblePl2}
              clickableRatings = {clickableRatings}
              onClick={ratingObj => setRatingObj(ratingObj)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default CardsBoard
```

Then in the card component I am returning the `ratingObj` successfully when the user clicks on a rating.

In the Card Component I have something like this:-

```
          <div
            className="col-md-2 text-left card-rating-color"
            onClick={() =>
              onClick({
                player: player,
                title: row[0].title,
                rating: row[0].rating,
              })
            }
          >
            {row[0].rating}
          </div>
```

However I am puzzled why `useEffect()` is triggered even when the Card component is loaded, and `ratingObj` is still empty.  Shouldn't it be triggered only if the `ratingObj` is filled up?

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding correctly, but do you want useEffect to ONLY be called when ratingObj is filled up? In your current code, useEffect will trigger when CardsBoard renders, and then when ratingObj is changed

Comment: Your code as posted won't even run, you don't define `ratingObj` or `setRatingObj`. And `useEffect` will always run at least once, on mount.

Comment: @AndréKrosby Yes I would like the useEffect to only be called if I have a click, ie the ratingObj will be filled up.  Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how your program works, but I guess you could add an if-condition inside the useEffect, something like 
```useEffect(() => {
if (ratingObj) {
  doRatingClickProcessing()
  }
}, [ratingObj])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useEffect will call at least once. it doesn't matter either your object is updating or not because when you write
useEffect(()=>{
},[ratingObj]);

In above code you are passing object into square brackets right. That means you are mentioning dependencies as e second parameter and empty [] in argument list will call once at least. After that, it depends on ratingObj that you have passed in.

Comment: is there a way to make the useEffect only run when ratingObj is filled up, maybe some other hook?

Comment: tried   useMemo(() => {
    doRatingClickProcessing()
  }, [ratingObj])
but I am getting doRatingClickProcessing() is not a function

Comment: Try to implement doRatingClickProcessing() before useMemo() as arrow function will not support hoisting.

Comment: still no luck.  Could this be the problem?  This is how I am declaring ratingObj  const [ratingObj, setRatingObj] = useState({}).  This will never be empty eh?

Comment: Do one thing you if you want your useEffect to be called on ratingObj changes only then you can add a if condition in useEffect(). I am sorry for the delay. I was out of courage.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {useState,useMemo} from 'react';
const App = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [modifiedName, setModifiedName] = useState('');
  const handleOnChange = (event) => {
    setName(event.target.value);
  }
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    setModifiedName(name);
  }
  const titleName = useMemo(()=>{
    console.log('hola');
    return `${modifiedName} is a Software Engineer`;
  },[modifiedName]);
  return (
    <div>
        <input type="text" value={name} onChange={handleOnChange} />
        <button type="button" onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
        <Title name={titleName} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;

const Title = ({name}) => {
  return <h1>{name}</h1>
}
```

Comment: This may be a correct answer, but the answer could be improved by adding an explanation of why it solves the problem

Comment: Premal my onClick is happening from the child component, so I cannot do it this way. I have to get the object from the child component

Comment: Premal, I did manage to fix my issue.  I set a flag inside my doRatingClickProcessing function, and it will only run if the ratingObj is not empty.  Basically I am checking that the player is not null,  and this is working.  Will give you the Answer though.